# SQL group by months, display empty months

Tags: mysql

I got an sql fiddle for this with minimal data. My Database contains over 1000 output columns for my query which I couldnt load into sqlFiddle.

I would like to display ALL months for all years found.
In my example Car 1 was only sold in 2003 and I would like to display all empty months for 2003.

For Car 2 it was sold in 2003 and 2004. So I would like to display all empty months for 03 and 04.

I have read a lot of similar questions and I think a simple JOIN to a month table should do the trick. But I dont know how to do joins properly.
Could anyone help me out on this one?

SQL Fiddle here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14b2f5/3

Also my real query in my mysql workbench and its output look like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPmsO.png). You can see that Feb. 2003 is missing there.
I would like to display "1952 Alpine Renault 1300" - "0" - "February 2003" instead of nothing like it is now.

Comment: If it was me, I'd probably handle the issue of missing dates in application code.

Comment: I suspect (hope) you have 1000 rows, not 1000 columns!